# How to invoke the servlet direclty to show the output on the JSP site?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, dao

My question is how to make it work so that I run the servlet in Eclipse JEE and it shows a jsp site with a data table as result in it? Usually, the whole page is empty or I see only the table column names only. I'm connected to my database in the meantime, that shouldn't be the problem.

This is the servlet. I suppose the problem must be in here somewhere.

```
@WebServlet("/StudentListService") 
public class StudentListServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

        try {
            StudentDAO studentDAO = new StudentDAO();
            studentList = studentDAO.getAllStudents();
            request.setAttribute("studentList", studentList);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("StudentList.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

This is the related DAO method. I have used this DAO class in earlier exercises, it should be ok.

```
public ArrayList<Student> getAllStudents() throws SQLException {
        ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        Connection dbConnection = null;
    try {
        dbConnection = openConnection();

        String sqlText = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname, streetaddress, postcode, postoffice FROM Student";

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sqlText);

        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
            String firstName = resultSet.getString("firstname");
            String lastName = resultSet.getString("lastname");
            String street = resultSet.getString("streetaddress");
            String postCode = resultSet.getString("postcode");
            String postOffice = resultSet.getString("postoffice");

            studentList.add(new Student(id, firstName, lastName, street, postCode, postOffice));
        }

        return studentList;

    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle; // Let the caller decide what to do with the exception

    } finally {
        closeConnection(dbConnection);
    }

}
```

This is the jsp. I'm not sure if it is correct, this is only the jsp part of it, it should show it in a html table.

```
<c:forEach items="${ studentList }" var="studentObject">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${ studentObject.id}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${ studentObject.lastName }" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${ studentObject.firstName }" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${ studentObject.street }" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${ studentObject.postCode}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${ studentObject.postOffice }" /></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: to access servlet directly make a get request to your servlet from you browser like this: http://localhost:8080/your-porject-name/StudentListService

Comment: @ZeeshanBinIqbal should we fix the context path in Config?

Comment: @fawad, why? its just a get request to servlet(doget method which is redirecting to jsp page.)

Comment: @ZeeshanBinIqbal wouldnt be it simple that way

Comment: Thanks for your answers! The problem was that the database jar was not included in the tomcat library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to access servlet directly make a get request to your servlet from you browser like this: localhost:8080/your-porject-name/StudentListService

Comment: Thanks for the answers! After all, the main problem was that I had the database jar only in the reference library and not in the tomcat.